# Mysql - On Duplicate Key Insert A Different Value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called history that tracks changes made to another table. The basic idea is to be able to track who last updated a specific entry.

When I insert the first time it will create an entry that shows the action field as 'UPLOAD'. The next time that same key is entered I need it to create a new history where the action is 'UPDATE', that way I can see when it was first made and who updated that key after that.

Unfortunately ON DUPLICATE KEY INSERT... is not a mysql construct. 
What do I do?

So far I have:

```
INSERT INTO history (key,userID,action,note,date)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

*Where the value of action is always 'UPLOAD', even if it's an update 
** The question marks are from the prepared statement bind

If the key exists in history I need the action to change to 'UPDATE' and create a new entry - it should never change entries that already exist.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you want to happen when a duplicate is inserted.

Comment: You need set your key column is Primary Key and Auto Increament (as 1, 2, 4....)

Comment: I've edited the question to be more clear

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen When duplicate key is found create a new history entry where the action is 'UPDATE' instead of 'UPLOAD'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can use triggers

   ```
   CREATE TRIGGER catchHim BEFORE INSERT ON myTable
   FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
       IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE userID=NEW.userID) THEN
           INSERT INTO history (key,userID,action,note,date) VALUES (NEW.myColumn1, NEW.myColumnForUserId, .....);
       END IF;
     END;
   ```

But they are hard to keep track of, especially that nobody uses them on MySQL.

2. Actually verify if that thing exists, in PHP, before making the update, then deciding whether to insert history or not.

Comment: I was thinking about verifying if it exists prior to inserting, but I feel it will take too long querying sql from php, (these values coming in are from a huge Excel Spreadsheet).

Comment: That's unavoidable. You either do it explicitly, or the DB engine does it before sending you off with an error. But it's fast, since it's probably a primary key, therefore a clustered index. So don't worry.

Comment: Cool! I'll give it a try. Thanks for your help!